# RxJS filter a list based on a list

Tags: reactive-programming, observable, rxjs

If I have a list where the number of arguments vary (or can be updated):

```
SomeDynamicListofPreferences = [
 'Chocolate',
 'Strawberry',
 'Vanilla'
];
```

What (if any) would be a good RxJS way to dynamically filter a list of matches based on a main source stream?

```
StockedFlavors = [
 'Almond Mocha',
 'Banana',
 'Butter Pecan',
 'Chocolate',
 'Coconut Cream',
 ...
 'Strawberry',
 'Vanilla'
];
```

Ex: Based on what I've learned so far one possibility is:

```
let dynamicPreferences = Rx.Observable.fromArray(SomeDynamicListofPreferences);
let StockedStream = Rx.Observable.fromArray(StockedFlavors);

let PrefMatches = StockedStream.filter((flavor) => 
  dynamicPreferences.includes(flavor) ).
subscribe((x) => { if(x){  /*...do stuff */ }});
```

The "includes" operator feels like a loop within a loop.  I could see another scenario of iterating the raw SomeDynamicListofPreferences to generate individual filterStreams.

Any help regarding technique and/or scale is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are these really just arrays, or is there something asynchronous going on?  If they're just two arrays, you could certainly compute their intersection more efficiently than with the nested .find().  Otherwise, you might consider turning `SomeDynamicListofPreferences` into a simple object to speed up lookups: `StockedStream.filter((flavor) => 
  dynamicPreferencesObj[flavor] !== undefined)`, or perhaps using a `Set`.

Comment: To summarize it - you wish to pass only values already streamed by different Observable?

Answer (score 0):

this works for me... ymmv

```
function deferSource(source) {
  // wrapping in the defer gives us a unique snowflake observable
  return Rx.Observable.defer(function() {
    // your returned observable may vary as well... 
    return Rx.Observable.fromArray(source);
  })
}

// your observable sources may vary
var preferenceList = [
 'Chocolate',
 'Strawberry',
 'Vanilla'
];

var flavorList = [
 'Almond Mocha',
 'Banana',
 'Butter Pecan',
 'Chocolate',
 'Coconut Cream',
 'Strawberry',
 'Vanilla Bean'
];

var prefrence$ = deferSource(preferenceList)
var flavor$ = deferSource(flavorList);

function curryQuery(static$source) {
  return function querySourceForResults(dynamic_element) {
    return static$source
      .filter(function(static_element){
        return static_element.includes(dynamic_element)
      })
  }
}

prefrence$.flatMap(curryQuery(flavor$)).subscribe(logger('result'))
```